# Are there any languages where you can put the demonstrative at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentences

Basically, are there any languages where it's grammatically acceptable to say "blue this is" rather than "this is blue?"

Comment: Do you mean sentences like this?

Comment: The demonstrative _isn’t_ at the end of the sentence in “blue this is”.

Comment: It's an interesting question, that.

Comment: "is" is the verb here, "this" is a demonstrative, although in this sentence it's behaving as a pronoun and can go in any position a noun could

Comment: Any languages that met these conditions would be verb-initial, and Salishan languages might meet the conditions (which aren't exactly spelled out in the question). However, typically Lushootseed, for instance, doesn't allow more than one NP per sentence, with everything else being determined by affixes and context. In Lushootseed (which is reasonably typical of its family) the root comes first, and then morphology happens.

Answer (score 4):

[The Malagasy language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_language#Word_order) has a verb–object–subject (VOS) word order, so in the sentence “This is blue” the subject “this” is the last word in the corresponding Malagasy sentence:

> English: This is blue.
> Malagasy: Manga ity.

*Manga* “blue”;
*ity* “this”.

The verb “to be” is not used in Malagasy just like in other Austronesian languages.

Comment: this answers the question as phrased in the title, but from the body of the text it appears Rachel actually wants languages with OSV (possibly also SOV) word orders

Answer (score 2):

Classical Latin allows such a word order e.g. "caeruleus ille est" (literally "blue that is"). This word order, with the predicate first adds emphasis to it, and "ille caeruleus est" (literally "that blue is") would be more common. The word "est" is also often dropped.

The choice of a verb like "is" here (a copula) rather than a simple transitive verb like "eats" complicates things a little, because these verbs sometimes use different syntax (they don't really have a subject and object in the same way as transitive verbs). Looking at the transitive case though, an order "apples horses eat" to mean "horses eat apples" is Object-Subject-Verb, or OSV.

Languages in which this word order is the default, unmarked word order are extremely unusual, the [World Atlas of Language Structures](https://wals.info/feature/81A#4/-10.57/292.59) listing just four languages with OSV as their default word order.